# CSS failing with positions

Tags: jquery, css, position, slide

Ok, i have this page and i added some jquery to slide some fields down if needed. But when i do that my textarea's become floating in the page where they would've been if the div wasn't slid down. I store them in tables with fixed layouts so that might be something. Does anyone know a way to get this over with?
Thanks in advance!

```
<table width='100%' style='table-layout:fixed'>
<tr>
<td width='60%'>
<body>
<form action='javascript:sendComment($idMe)' method='POST'>";
<textarea onkeypress='return process(event, $idMe);' onkeydown='shift(event)' onfocus='commentboxfocus($idMe)' onblur='commentboxblur($idMe)' class='text' id='com$idMe' wrap='hard'  style='wrap:hard;height:30px;width:100%;position:relative' name='comment'>Type a comment!</textarea>
<input type='hidden' name='comid' value='$idMe' id='comid$idMe'>
<br>
<span id='comstatus$idMe'></span>
</form>
</td>
<td width='60px'>
<b id='LDStatusLike$idMe'  style='color:green'>$likeMe</b><br><a href='#' onclick='likeThis($idMe); return false;'><img src='+1.png' style='border:1px solid darkblue'></a>
</td>
<td width='60px'>
<b id='LDStatusDislike$idMe' style='color:red'>$dislikeMe</b><br><a href='#' onclick='dislikeThis($idMe); return false;'><img src='-1.png' style='border:1px solid darkblue'></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

is a small part containing the textareas...

Comment: Can you post up the HTML and the script you are using please?

Comment: please share some codes, for example.

Comment: the script is ENORMOUS so that is not really a good idea so...

Comment: Make a small mockup of the problem.

Comment: i feel kinda shitty i had a position relative set for the comment boxes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would help if you included some code, but from your description you need to assign  in CSS `position:absolute;` to those elements that you are sliding down.